# Как проверить, является ли apache бэкэндом для nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, nginx, ssh

Есть сервер на *Ubuntu 14.04.3*, и к нему есть доступ по *SSH*.
На сервере установлен *nginx/1.4.6* и *Apache/2.4.7*

Но вот в чем вопрос. Работают ли в паре *Nginx+Apache*?
То есть, является ли *nginx* «фронтэндом», а *apache* «бэкэндом»?

Есть ли какая нибудь *ssh*-команда, которая бы показала это?

Comment: А вы уверены, что именно apache бэкенд для nginx, а не наоборот?

Comment: @Foxtrot, посмотри глазами в конфигах nginx (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf и дальше в инклюды)

Comment: @norbornen,  я слишком долго смотрел в вопрос и не так его понял. Естественно, nginx не может быть бэкендом. По крайней мере мне об этом ничего не известно.

Comment: @norbornen, бэкендом для nginx много что может быть.

Comment: @ВикторРэд, прошу прощения, я не внимательно прочёл твой комментарий. удалил свои

Comment: @ВикторРэд, *Естественно, nginx не может быть бэкендом* — запросто, ведь *nginx* — полноценный *http*-сервер. при желании можно использовать даже связку *apache+nginx* «наоборот» — чтобы *apache* проксировал запросы к *nginx*-у. только так вряд ли кто-то делает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться такой командой:

```
$ sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -c nginx -c apache -c httpd -a
```

и проанализировать её вывод. пример (реальный сервер, часть строк опущена для наглядности):

```
COMMAND   PID                USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2  2206                root    3u  IPv4 58834967      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
apache2 13377            www-data    3u  IPv4 58834967      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
nginx   13289                root    6u  IPv4 58829785      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   13289                root    7u  IPv4 58829786      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx   13624            www-data    6u  IPv4 58829785      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   13627            www-data    7u  IPv4 58829786      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

из него видно, что *nginx* слушает 80-й и 443-й порты на всех адресах (`*:80` и `*:443`), а *apache* — лишь порт 8080 и только на адресе 127.0.0.1 (`127.0.0.1:8080`).

откуда вытекает вполне логичный вывод: *nginx* слушает внешние обращения и (возможно) передаёт (некоторые из них) *apache*-у.

---

«расшифровка» использованных опций программы `lsof`:

- `-P` — отображать номера портов, а не имена, взятые из файла `/etc/services`
- `-n` — отображать *ip*-адреса, не пытаясь преобразовать их в доменные имена
- `-iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` — отобразить процессы, слушающие *tcp*-порты
- `-c nginx -c apache -c httpd` — отобразить процессы, начинающиеся с этих строк
- `-a` — логическое *and* для параметров (правда, не для всех: в данном случае применяется для «связывания» `-iTCP` и `-c имя`). если его опустить, то будут выведены ещё и открытые указанными (с помощью опций `-c`) процессами файлы (вообще программа *lsof* в первую очередь для отображения открытых файлов и писалась).

Answer (score 2):

Можно посмотреть, кто какие порты слушает:

`sudo lsof -i | grep LISTEN`

Напр. у меня выводит что-то вроде:

```
nginx     22633     root   27u  IPv4 82311419      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     22633     root   28u  IPv4 82311420      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx     22635   nobody   27u  IPv4 82311419      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     22635   nobody   28u  IPv4 82311420      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

Тут видно, что по портам 80 (http) и 443 (https) слушает nginx. Т.е. обращения к вашему серверу по этим портам принимает он.

А Apache, в случае если nginx проксирует соединения к Apache, слушает на порту 8080, или другом «нестандартном». Посмотрите всю подряд информацию о портах:

`sudo lsof -i`

или grep'ом выделите оттуда только "apache2" или 'httpd" или как там ещё могут называться процессы Apache.

А потом можно отправиться смотреть конфиги nginx и Apache подробнее.